# Firefox: access a button that belongs to an extension using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I have an extension that, when I click its icon in the Firefox toolbar, opens a pop-up menu with some buttons. I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to one of these buttons. Is that possible?

Comment: Regrettably, I know of no way directly, or with some add-on, to "click" an extension using a keyboard shortcut. It *would* be a nice feature. For example, I often click on *Clear Browsing Data*, and woould like a keyboard short to do so.